# What are these "unexplained similarities" between Celtic languages and languages from North Africa?

Tags: historical-linguistics, indo-european, celtic, afroasiatic

In the section "The linguistic relationship of Welsh" from the book *"Modern Welsh: a comprehensive grammar"* by Gareth King we can find the following quote:

> Celtic also shows
> unexplained similarities with certain languages of North Africa.

What are the (probably coincidental(?)) similarities between the Celtic group and these north Africa languages? And which specific african languages is he referring to?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The similarities usually cited between Insular Celtic and the Semitic languages and those of North Africa are the following:

- VSO as basic word order.
- "Conjugated" prepositions, where prepositions governing a pronominal object fuse with a clitic, rather than simply being followed by the independent form of the pronoun. E.g. Hebrew לי li "to me" instead of *ל־אני *l-ʾani.
- "Construct" state, where genitive phrases come in the form "[regens] (article) [rectum]" (the regens is the possessed object, and the rectum is the possessor), where the presence of the definite article instead of giving the definiteness of the rectum gives the definiteness of the entire phrase. E.g. Hebrew בֵּית סֵפֶר bēt séfer "a school" (lit. house-of book" & בֵּית הַסֵּפֶר‎ ‎bēt ha-séfer "the school" (lit. "house of the-book").

  - A construct state is often described as being a case-like marking of the possessed object in a genitive phrase. By this definition the Insular Celtic languages lack such a similarity.

Unexplained is a massive overstatement. None of these are especially unusual cross-linguistically, and transition to these from more typical Indo-European norms are also well-attested globally.

Vennemann argues for a Semitic (or sometimes some other Afroasiatic) substrate in Celtic and Germanic. His work ignores the fact that these similarities are absent in the earliest stages of the Insular Celtic languages (e.g. Primitive Irish in Ogham inscriptions, and Brythonic inscriptions of the Roman era), and so any contact would need to have occurred during the historical era, and if it was sufficiently intense to cause such major structural changes and in such an era, we absolutely would see evidence of it that we do not. His ideas in this regard are pretty fringe.

It's also worth noting that conjugated prepositions do occur to a limited extent in other Indo-European languages e.g. Spanish con "with" has a full set of conjugated forms like conmigo "with-me".

Comment: I thought the defining feature of the construct state was that the _regens_ (rather than the rectum) has a particular case(-like) form. The fact that a definite article on the rectum makes the whole phrase definite is exceedingly common, including in Germanic, so hardly unexpected in Celtic.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet when the regens precedes the rectum such marking is much less common. In Germanic it's also more accurate to say the article precedes the noun phrase (as seen by the fact adjectives lie between the article and noun). You are right though that a construct state is usually defined in such a way, but Celtic languages don't fit such a definition, the only real one they have is the definiteness marking

Comment: The article also precedes the noun phrase in Celtic (visible in the few cases where adjectives precede nouns, like Irish _teach an chéad fhir_ ‘the first man’s house’). It’s true that in some parts of Germanic the rectum’s (rectal?) article only controls the entire phrase in the opposite order (German _des Mannes Haus_ vs _**das** Haus des Mannes_), though not everywhere (Icelandic _mannsins hús_ vs _hús mannsins_ – though usually _húsið hans_). I can’t think of many other [regens rectum] examples now, so I’ll take your word for the relative frequency.

Comment: Oh, also: the Hebrew example actually **doesn’t** match Celtic languages. In an indefinite collocation akin to _bēt séfer_, such as Irish _teach tábhairne_ ‘pub [lit. house of-tavern]’, making it definite would be done by adding the article to the whole phrase (_an teach tábhairne_). Adding it to the rectum (_teach an tábhairne_) would still result in a definite NP, but it’s only definite because the rectum is definite; i.e., it would mean ‘(the) house of the tavern’ rather than ‘the pub’.

Comment: huh, in that case I've no idea why people bring up a Celtic genitive phrases as construct-state-like, because that just looks like a pretty typical genitive construction

Comment: wait, wikipedia quotes: Breton dor an ti [door the house] 'the door of the house', Welsh: drŵs y tŷ [door the house] 'the door of the house', Irish: doras an tí [door.NOMINATIVE the-house.GENITIVE] 'the door of the house'. It also says only the rectum is marked for definiteness

Comment: My Welsh is quite limited (and my Breton and Cornish virtually nonexistent), but I’m _fairly_ sure it works the same there. The regent can’t take a definite article, only the rectum, but the possessive phrase as a whole can take the article as long as the rectum is indefinite; so you can have _gwaed uncorn_ ‘unicorn blood’ and _gwaed yr uncorn_ ‘blood of the unicorn / the unicorn’s blood’ (blood from a specific unicorn), but also _y gwaed uncorn_ ‘the unicorn blood’ (specific blood of the generic unicorn type).

Comment: What you **can’t** have is double definiteness, à la _*an doras an tí_, _*y drŵs y tŷ_, _*an dor an ti_. That’s not valid anywhere. If the rectum is definite, the entire possessive will be inherently definite and cannot be overtly marked; but if the rectum is indefinite, the entire phrase can be overtly marked. I don’t know if _ha-bēt séfer_ would be valid in Hebrew, but that would be how the Celtic languages would make the phrase definite _without_ making the rectum specifically definite.

Comment: ha-bēt séfer is not valid in Hebrew. Tbh at this point the "construct state" similarity seems to be entirely bogus. The fact you can't have both parts definite is the only similarity but as Semitic has a _much_ tighter restriction (only the rectum can be marked, and its marking reflects the semantic definiteness of the entire phrase) this seems about as useful a "similarity" as the fact that Welsh and Biblical Hebrew both have /ɬ/

Comment: @Tristan FWIW, *ha-bet sefer* is common in colloquial Modern Hebrew (though prescriptively frowned on); if one wanted to salvage the theory maybe one could appeal to a similar development in Celtic.

Comment: @TKR in that case the timeline is even more divergent though, so I'm not sure it actually does help, it just pushes the problems to a slightly different point

Answer (score 0):

One feature that immediately comes to my mind is the basic word order VSO of Insular Celtic shared with Berber languages of North Africa, Standard Arabic, and Phoenician.

*Unexplained* is a strong word used here, at least some scholars (e.g. Vennemann) argued for a Semitic substrate to Celtic and Germanic languages.

Comment: Do you have any citations for a Semitic substrate to Germany and Celtic? First time I'm hearing that.

Comment: Very quick link to [Vennemann's Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theo_Vennemann). Vennemann wrote a lot along these lines. His views are definitely not mainstream, but he's also not a crackpot.

Comment: I have heard of this supposed connection as well, but do not give it much credence.  Another similarity is that prepositions are "conjugated" by providing them with pronoun suffixes.  I think this is now just considered a normal side effect of being VSO.